# Sort floating point values from a file (read/write)

Tags: c, file, sorting, floating-point, read-write

I am writing a C program that should sort floats (increasingly). The values are saved in a file and then after the sort, the values are saved into the same file. I am using library functions to read and write. I am using radixsort to sort the floats.

This is the code I currently have. Rather than the array being populated with values from the file that I am reading, it is storing 0.000000 for every index. I am not sure where I am going wrong in my implementation.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(float *a, float *b, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        float tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = b[i];
        b[i] = tmp;
    }
}
void radixSort(float array[], size_t count)
{
    int numZeroes=0;
    float tempArr1[count];
    float * tempArr2 = tempArr1;
    for (uint32_t radix=1;radix;radix<<=1){
        uint32_t * intArray = (uint32_t *)array;
        int count0=0;
        int count1=0;
        numZeroes=0;
        for (int j=0; j<count; ++j)
        numZeroes += !(intArray[j]&radix);
        count1=numZeroes;
        for (int j=0; j < count; ++j)
        if (intArray[j]&radix){
            tempArr2[count1]=array[j];
            ++count1;
        }
        else{
            tempArr2[count0]=array[j];
            ++count0;
        }
        swap(tempArr2,array,count);
    }
    if (numZeroes<count){
        memcpy( tempArr2+(count-numZeroes), array, numZeroes*sizeof(float));
        
        for (int d=0,j=count-1;j>=numZeroes;j--,d++)
        tempArr2[d]=array[j];
        memcpy( array, tempArr2, count * sizeof(float));
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fd, *writeFile;
    int i = 0;  
    float number; 
    int elementnum = 0; 
    
    struct stat st; 
    int fd2; 
    
    fd=fopen(argv[1], "r");
    fd2 = fileno(fd); 
    
    if(fd==NULL){
        printf("Error opening file\n");
    }
    
    fstat(fd2, &st); 
    off_t size = st.st_size;
    for(int j = 0; j < size/4; j++){
        elementnum++;
    }
    
    float array[elementnum];
    while(fscanf(fd, "%f", &number)==1) {
        array[i] = number;
        i++;
    }
    
    radixSort(array,elementnum);  
    
    for(int j = 0; j < elementnum; j++){
        printf("%f\n", array[j]);
    }
  
    fclose(fd);
    
    writeFile=fopen("argv[1]", "w");
    for(int j = 0; j < elementnum; j++){
        fprintf(writeFile, "%f\n", array[j]);  
    }
    fclose(writeFile);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless you have very specific requirements on your sorting, I really recommend that you use [the standard `qsort` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort).

Comment: As for the current code you have and how to fix it, take this as a good opportunity to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. Start with the smallest input set leading to your problem, and debug that.

Comment: I don't understand why you base the number of lines of input file (`elementnum`) on the filesize/st_size rather than on the actual number of lines. This is giving wrong number of lines btw, and hence the 0.000000

Answer (score 0):

At least these issues:

Code is assuming the size of the *text* file divided by 4 is the number of `float`.  This is risky and error prone.  [@agus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139741/sort-floating-point-values-from-a-file-read-write/65140969#comment115161718_65139741)

Instead of `fstat(fd2, &st);`, count them

```
size_t elementnum = 0;
while(fscanf(fd, "%f", &number)==1) {
    elementnum++;
}

rewind(fd);

float array[elementnum];

for (i=0; i < elementnum; i++) {
  if (fscanf(fd, "%f", &number) != 1) {
    puts("We have trouble reading the same on the 2nd pass");
    exit(1);
  }
  array[i] = number;
}

radixSort(array, elementnum);
```

`/ 4` might make sense with a *binary* file and using `fread()` to read `float`.

---

> it is storing 0.000000 for every index

Writing `float` with `"%f"` is uninformative with small values.  Better to use `"%e"` or `"%g"`.

```
#include <float.h>

// fprintf(writeFile, "%f\n", array[j]);
fprintf(writeFile, "%g\n", array[j]);    
// or better
fprintf(writeFile, "%.*g\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, array[j]);
```